# How can I obtain a decrypted SAML token from an encrypted SAML token?

Tags: c#, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I have a client website utilizing ADFS for SSO, and it appears the domain is hosted within the same ADFS instance. When I execute my code, it successfully provides a decrypted SAML token, likely because they share the same ADFS. However, my client has multiple ADFS instances, and users can log in across those domains. When I input my user ID and password for my main ADFS user, I receive a decrypted SAML token. Yet, when logging in to other ADFS instances (e.g., ADFS 1, ADFS 2), I receive an encrypted SAML token. Now, it seems I need to send this encrypted SAML token, obtained from another ADFS, to the main ADFS for decryption and to receive the appropriate SAML token. How can I achieve this in C#?

```
C# code to get SAML token
 string adfsendpoint1 = "https://example.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";

                WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                new EndpointAddress(adfsendpoint1)
                );
                factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
                var channelCredentials = factory.Credentials;
                channelCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;  //User Name of ADFS user
                channelCredentials.UserName.Password = password;  //Password of ADFS user
                channelCredentials.SupportInteractive = false;
                RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                {
                    RequestType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
                    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(relyingPartyId),
                    KeyType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,

                };




                IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                        (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
                        {
                            return true;
                        };
                GenericXmlSecurityToken genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;

                string tokenXml = "<Root>" + genericToken.TokenXml.InnerXml + "</Root>";



[Image of multiple adfs login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP0rp.png)
```

I'm looking for the continuation of my code to handle the decrypted SAML token obtained from another ADFS instance.